# How to disable BIOS update feature in Ubuntu 17.10/18.04?

Tags: 17.10, 18.04, bios

I'm trying to disable the BIOS/firmware update, I had a bad experience with the automated process, I rather do it manually. It bricked my computer, motherboard had to be replaced, luckly I had warranty.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: The question is not clear. BIOS updates have nothing to do with Ubuntu. There is no "BIOS update feature" in Ubuntu.

Comment: You are wrong. The update above actually updates the Bios. System firmware =BIOS

Comment: Maybe it is some custom XPS feature.

Comment: I don't think so. I guess it's a Uefi feature

Comment: I don't have this feature on any of my PCs.

Comment: Linux developers are about to release UEFI update features, but both system & hardware have to support that. The firmware update is internal to Linux and is drivers. These have to be updated to resolve hardware issues and protect against Meltdown and Spectre CPU vulnerabilities. To OPs point there were some early Intel updates that had to be rolled back to previous version, but that is very unusual.

Comment: @Pilot6 Ubuntu has `fwupdmgr` for BIOS updates when manufacturers support it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The software responsible for this type of update is `fwupd`.

> fwupd is a simple daemon to allow session software to update device firmware on your local machine. It's designed for desktops, but this project is also usable on phones, tablets and on headless servers. You can either use a GUI software manager like GNOME Software to view and apply updates, the command-line tool or the system D-Bus interface directly.

To get rid of the updates you can uninstall `fwupd` easily:

```
sudo apt-get remove fwupd
```

<sup>([Source](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/fwupd?action=remove))</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Stop the service, disable automatic start upon boot, and disable manual invoking with:

```
sudo systemctl stop fwupd.service
sudo systemctl disable fwupd.service
sudo systemctl mask fwupd.service
```